# Javascript is not hiding div & input element

Tags: javascript, input, toggle, hidden

I've got a div & input that needs to be hidden on the page load.  It is a other specify, so if one of the other fields is selected "other" then the div should show.  But the input element is not hiding on page load.  As soon as I take out the input element from the div it hides, but as soon as I put the input element back it does not hide, what am I doing wrong?

```
<head>
<script>
function hideother() {
    document.getElementById("otherdiv").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("others").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
</script>
</head>

<body onLoad="hideother()">
    <!-- 2A OTHER SPECIFY -->
    <div class="otherdiv">
    <label for="otherspecify">Please specify other:</label>
    <label id="error-2" style="text-transform:capitalize; color:red">&nbsp;</label>
    <br>
<input maxlength="30" name="others" id="others" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Other Specify" autocomplete="off" style="width:300px" />
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: `otherdiv` is a class and you're trying to reference it with `getElementById`

Comment: You shouldn't be using Javascript to set the initial state of elements - that's what css is for.  Set the states later with js, by all means, but this isn't the way to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

change

```
<div class="otherdiv">
```

to

```
<div id="otherdiv">
```

Comment: For OP, see this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/03cofp5e/). Might help

Comment: I see in the fiddle that it works, I changed it to id and not class but still not working, as soon as I add the input element it is not working

Comment: @wilest Did you try the fiddle from my answer?

Answer (score 2):

Change `class="otherdiv"` to `id="otherdiv"`. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/12Lokrgp/) for a working example.

Answer (score 0):

Change `class='otherdiv'` to `id='otherdiv'`